# How to get the name of .png file programmatically+iphone

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to get the name of image(.png) which is in uiimageview.

Example:

```
TouchImageView *touchImageView = [[TouchImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 53, 70, 70)];
touchImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"];
```

Now in somewhere in code I want to get that tounchImageview is having the image name Cirlce.png

How can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not possible to turn an UIImage into the name used with [UIImage imageNamed:].

Comment: This. You're going to have to figure some other way to figure out what image is there.

Answer (score 1):

Store that image name at some place.

For example, you can user NSUserDefaults or you can also store it in database.

I prefer `NSUserDefaults`.